# Changing root view of view controller ends up with a black view

Tags: ios, objective-c

What I'm trying to achieve is a view controller that can display the items in both list form and collection form with a button that can switch over between two display options.

So what I've implemented is a `UIViewController` that can hold both `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`.

When this view controller loads at the first time, the `UITableView` appears fine. But when I press the switching button (it simply changes `self.view` to `UICollectionView`), it ends up with just a black view.

and when I try to get back to the `UITableView` by pressing switching button (again, it just changes `self.view` to previous `UITableView`), nothing happens. It just stays black.

Is there something that I should do after changing the root view of view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended behavior to change the view of a `UIViewController` past the point in time at which `loadView` is called. You'll want your view controller to have one, persistent view for its lifetime. I'd recommend one of the following.

1. Layering the table view / collection view *on top of* your view controller's view. That way you're not monkeying with the main underlying view itself.
2. Having two instances of your view controller, one with a table and the other with a collection view, and swapping between those.

Comment: I just found out that removing a `UIScrollView` from superview causes `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to break when device orientation changes. Just like what you said, I totally agree with that it is a not recommended behavior to change the view. I should implement the collection view and table view as a subviews of  `self.view` and use `setHidden` to swap between two display options.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only switching the `subviews` of `self.view` object.

```
var tableView:UITableView?
var collectionView:UICollectionView?
var bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480) // frame of tableView

func createTableView() -> UITableView{
    if(tableView == nil){
        tableView = UITableView(frame: bounds, style: .Plain)
    }
    tableView?.delegate = self
    tableView?.dataSource = self

    return tableView;
}

func createCollectionView() -> UICollectionView{
    if(collectionView == nil){
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: bounds, collectionViewLayout: CustomFlowLayout)
    }
    collectionView?.delegate = self
    collectionView?.dataSource = self
    return collectionView
}

func initializeViews{
    createTableView()
    createCollectionView()
    self.view.addSubView(tableView);
    self.view.addSubView(collectionView);
}

func showTableView{
    collectionView?.hidden = true;
    tableView?.hidden = false;
}

func showCollectionView{
    tableView?.hidden = true;
    collectionView?.hidden = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I've tried this and got what I wanted! :)
Simply removed from superview and then added back.

```
UIView *superview = self.view.superview;
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
self.view = self.collectionView;
[superview addSubview:self.view];
```

Comment: Well, it turns out that removing scroll view from the view controller breaks the scroll view insets when device orientation changes :(